# Getting all of my own video links with vimeo API

Tags: vimeo-api

I want to perform a very specific task through vimeo api. Can anyone tell if it's possible? And if so, how can I do that?

I want to get all the links for the videos that I've uploaded on my vimeo account whether public / private / password protected. And also, is it possible to get the download links of the videos through the api?

Answer (score 1):

Make an authenticated `GET` request to `https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos`. I would recommend also using the [fields parameter](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/common-formats#json-filter) on the request, as the response can be quite large if you have many videos on your account.

The `/me/videos` endpoint is documented [here](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos#get_videos) (make sure you're logged into your Vimeo account).

Answer (score -1):

i think it is very easy.
you should take a look

https://api.vimeo.com/users/{user_id}/videos
https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos

this two are the way to get all videos